# SQL Server auto-identity unexpected reset/value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server
Version: 12.0.5556.0

**Problem**: SQL Server genereated an unexpected identity or did a reset on the auto-identity value

**Information**: I have a customer system which is running SQL Server 12.0.556.0 where, while testing phase I generated some test data which was deleted when the system was going live. So the identity value on this table startet at ~34.000 when the system was going into production in 2018.

Now after 2 years the identity value is at ~90.000, but a few days ago an entry with the identity 1 was created. When i query the table with `select IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')` it is showing a value of 90182.

Now to my **question**, is there any reason why SQL Server would suddenly change the identity value to 1 and then jump back to the current identity value of ~90.000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that someone set [`identity_insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to `ON` for the table and inserted the row.

Otherwise, you cannot insert an explicit value for an identity column.

And, `identity` is guaranteed to be an increasing value (although there may be gaps) when generated automatically.

Comment: Ok so the SQL Server does not fill those gaps on its own for some reason? 
Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Nope. SQL Server doesn't go back and fill in the gaps in any way.